# Setting a Cookie if Hash is Valid in URL

Tags: php, cookies

what I'm doing is passing a hash in the URL from `page1.php` to `page2.php` which has been working fine so far but instead of setting `$valid` to `TRUE` I want to set a cookie.

**Currently I have the code working like this:**

```
if ($hash === md5($key.$test_time)) $valid = TRUE;
```

**To set the cookie instead I tried this:**

```
if ($hash === md5($key.$test_time))
//set "Cookie" for 24 hours
$cookie_value = "Cookie";
setcookie("Placed", $cookie_value, time()+86400);
```

**I am getting these errors:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: cookie_value in /Dev/sites/files/page2.php on line 19

and

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Dev/sites/files/page2.php:19) in /Dev/sites/files/page2.php on line 19

How do I fix this so I can set a cookie instead of a value?

Comment: Your code seems to be working - [Example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#iMRdOFJgT), so Is this `line 19` on your `page2.php`?

Comment: @Darren yes the `setcookie` is line 19